# using joinpath() to insert a specific string to a longer string - similar R paste()

Tags: julia

Ok so this worked in 0.7.

```
tickers = ["IWB","IWP","IVV","IYY","IEV","EEM","TLT"]
t=1
res = joinpath("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_MONTHLY_ADJUSTED&symbol="tickers[t]"&outputsize=full&apikey=your_key&datatype=csv")
```

syntax: cannot juxtapose string literal

What changes were made in v1.1 or may someone suggest another way to insert the contents of tickers[t] to my path above.

R has `paste()` and `joinpath()` in `julia` was my replacement for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That definitely does not work in v0.7 (I just checked).

Any code pattern of the form:

```
"abc"d"efg"
```

will throw the same error, since Julia is attempting to construct a string literal object out of `d"efg"` and then juxtaposing it with the string `"abc"`. The operation you want here is string interpolation, eg:

```
ticker = "ABC"
res = "https://somepath/symbol=$(ticker)&morestuff"
```

Of course, you could also just use:

```
ticker = "ABC"
res = string("https://somepath/symbol=", ticker, "&morestuff")
```

I believe it used to be  true that calling `string` directly could be more efficient in some cases. But @DNF suggests (in comments) that both approaches lower to the same  code now so use whichever syntax you  prefer. Personally I find the interpolation code syntax cleaner. In the context of the operation you are performing (requesting stock data) the efficiency differences are meaningless anyway.

I'm not really sure why you're trying to use `joinpath` at all here, since `joinpath` is used to build file/directory addresses for the current OS. Using `joinpath` to build URL strings is not a good idea since on a Windows OS, `joinpath` will use `\`, not `/`. Even `join`, which allows you to specify the delimiter used when joining, wouldn't really make sense here since you don't want a slash on either side of the ticker code.

Comment: As far as I know interpolation syntax gets lowered to a call to `string`, so the performance should be identical.

Comment: @DNF I must admit, I'm speaking from a vague memory of Stefan discussing cases where interpolation is slower from a thread that is at least a year old... Can't find it now. I'll adjust answer to reflect this.

Comment: I believe you are right that string interpolation isn't optimally fast, but you might be thinking of cases like `println("foo $bar baz")` vs `println("foo ", bar, " baz")`. Faster string construction is possible with `IOBuffer`, but I have no experience with that.